# Formatting Data for SAS

Tags: sas, data-entry

What should I expect when I actually upload a file? I'm trying to upload a text file with a bunch of columns each one giving data points for a categorical or numerical variable. SAS reads the file but then says 'invalid data for ***_*___**' for almost every line. Is there a straightforward way to format the columns of data so that SAS can read it?  Sample lines of data are as follows:

WCM2B   W   C   M   2   B   Z.G 2   18.4    10.7    g

WCM2B   W   C   M   2   B   Z.G 2   17.6    10.8    g

WCM2B   W   C   M   2   B   Z.G 2   20.1    12.1    g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still learning SAS but this should work.

```
data test_table;
input A $6. B $2. C $2. D $2. E 2. F $2. G $4. H $2. I 4. J 4. K $2.;
datalines;
WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 18.4 10.7 g
WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 17.6 10.8 g
WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 20.1 12.1 g
;run;
```

The data test_table; makes the table name, the input is the column name followed by number of spaces, then datalines is your data.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to do this though when importing a file?  I should have specified because there are a lot of data lines and it would be infeasible to type them all out.

Comment: If you're doing it that way, you should do `input A :$6.` - that's important.

Comment: Is that all that needs to change though?  data test_table, input, and so on, is that all the same?

Comment: To expand on @Joe 's comment.  You can find a description of what the colon operator does in section 2 of this whitepaper http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p073-26.pdf

Comment: Thanks.  I still can't seem to get it to work though.  Should those categorical variables not be changed?  How can I use the infile 'file_name' command to get the .txt file in?